# Finding field exist or not through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

My class structure is as follows

```
   ClassA{}
   ClassB extends ClassA{}
   ClassC extends ClassB{}
```

these classes contains a field say `name`, I did not know in which class this field is present, i have a `string name` and object of `ClassC`. I am using reflection to get the field my code is

```
  private static Field getType(Object obj,String fieldName){

            Field type = null;
            try
            {
                    type = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            } 
            catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    try
                    {
                            type = obj.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return type;
    }
```

But it will check for field only in the current class and its super class, if i want to check the field till top level class, I need to keep write try catch blocks. i think it is not the correct way. Is there any alternate solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See it in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324991/see-if-field-exists-in-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are trying to do something like:

```
   Class cls = obj.getClass();        
    for (Class acls = cls; acls != null; acls = acls.getSuperclass()) {
      try {
        Field field = acls.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        // if not found exception thrown
        // else return field
        return field;
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        // ignore
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`getField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `getDeclaredField`. It will look for the field in interfaces and parent classes recursively if it's not found immediately in the given class.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but all my fields are private so i can not get the fields using getfields i guess, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: If your fields are private, then the subclass would not have inherited them anyway.

Comment: Correct: `getField` only gets public fields.

Comment: @NickJ: you are write, So if i use getField, it is throwing nosuchfield exception, though my class has the field name(private)

Answer (score 2):

What about wrapping try block into the loop:

```
Field type = null;  
Class clz = object.getClass();
while(clz != null || clz != Object.class) {
    try
    {
        type = clz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        break;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        clz = object.getSuperclass();
    } 
}
return type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while (or any other similar) loop to keep scanning down until you find a match.

```
private static Field getType(Object obj,String fieldName){

Field type = null;
Class clazz = obj.getClass();
while (type==null && clazz!=null) {
   try {
       type = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
       clazz = clazz.getSuperClass();
   } catch (SecurityException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
   }
   return type;
}
```

It would be better to check if the field exists rather than using the exception to control flow but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will take care of superclass and nested properties.**

```
public static boolean isFieldExist(Class<?> clazz, String property) {
String[] fields = property.split("\\.");

    try {
        Field file = clazz.getDeclaredField(fields[0]);

        if (fields.length > 1) {
            return isFieldExist(file.getType(), property.substring(property.indexOf('.') + 1, property.length()));
        }

        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
            return isFieldExist(clazz.getSuperclass(), property);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```