# Reflection To check if field exist in containing class

Tags: java, reflection

```
class A{
   String name;
   B b;
}

class B{
   String text;
}
```

Now if I do A.class.getField("text");
This will give exception. How can I use reflection to see if field exist in Containing class B

If its a direct field in Class A reflection works. But if the field is within another containing Class Object(In this case class B) it wont retrieve the field

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324991/see-if-field-exists-in-class

Comment: In this the main class contains direct fields. But in my case 'B' is a separate class contained in class 'A' and that class B contains the field 'text'.

Comment: "if the field is within another containing Class Object(In this case class B) it wont retrieve the field" that is normal, you need to specify from which class you want to get that field and that field should be declared in that class or in its supertype. Otherwise if you have lets say `class A { B b; C c; }` and both `B` and `C` have their own `text` field, which one should `Field` object returned by `getField()` represent?

Comment: `B` is not “contained in class `A`”. Whether `B` has a field named `text` does not depend on `A`.